# General tips in running a Unity3D-Animation on Microsoft Hololens

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm going to have the task to make sure that an animation created for in Unity3D can be run on a Microsoft Hololens. I don't have any further information about the animation yet but I wanted to ask in advance if there are any big things i should keep in mind.
In the animation you're playing a "character" in first person mode, controlled by wasd or the arrow keys and you can look up, down, left, right with the mouse. There are (as known to me) no special interactions besides colliders.

And another question: is it easier to test the animation on the actual hololens or to use a hololens-emulator on my laptop?

I know it's a lot to ask right now without any code or stuff but I still hope that some of you can give me a little advide :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is difficult to say. The HoloLens, besides it is an awesome device with nice specs for that size, has quite limited graphical power. Try to minimize your model's vetices to a reasonable low amount (e.g. using Blender's decimate feature). Set down the quality in Unity's quality setting as proposed in the Dev-Guide.

For your emulation question: The emulator does not emulate the HoloLens' specs (like processor, memory...), but emulates input concepts etc., while running a Hyper-V virtual machine. So the performance in the emulator is dependent to your computer's hardware and is not related to the actual performance on a HoloLens.

Also take a look at the [performance guidelines from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/performance-recommendations-for-hololens-apps)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on HoloLens for a couple of projects. A few points that can be useful for you:

- the first big thing I would keep in my mind is understanding if the character has to move in a VR environment. In this case HoloLens is almost useless because its lenses will allow you to see the surroundings [the real ones] distracting you from the virtual world. This is exactly what happens with their pre-installed HoloTour. Nice attempt but you will not totally feel in Roma or Machu Picchu
- the second big thing that I would consider is the fact that - at least for the first release - HoloLens has a very limited field of view, that "amounts to the size of a monitor in front of you – equivalent to 15 inches" [[source](https://www.techradar.com/news/wearables/this-is-how-microsoft-s-hololens-will-address-its-biggest-flaw-1322596)]. It is likely that - in a situation where the character will look in every direction - the objects that you put in the AR space will end up being cut or invisible
- about testing: the emulator is really exceptional, I didn't find great differences between it and the real device. Of course if you already have the real HoloLens I would use that. But if not I would first develop and test on the emulator to understand if the project is worth the purchase